# Django template date format differs from printed output

Tags: django, templates, datetime, format, datefield

I'm having trouble with the output of dates in a table using Django.
I need the date output to the html to be in the default format (YYYY-MM-DD), but the output is in the format Month-Name Day, Year. For example, if the date were 2008-01-10, the template produces "January 10, 2008".
The troubling part is that, in views.py, I'm printing off the dates to the console, as they're being passed to the template, and they're in YYYY-MM-DD format. But somehow the template renders the dates incorrectly.
I've tried setting USE_L10N = False in settings.py, to no avail. I've even disconnected the template from any 'base templates' to ensure that there wasn't a css or javascript issue. But the misprints remain. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

```
{{ value|date:"Y-m-d" }}
```

Comment: The format I was looking for was value|date:"Y-m-d", but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me so there is no need of `SE_L10N = False` and other parameters:

```
{{ show.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}
```

Comment: Please have a read of the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve the formatting in your answer, and also check out [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is used for that

> {{ report.created_at|date:'m-d-Y H:i A' }}